# write to excel - loop through rows&columns missing data - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, .net-core, excelpackage

The following code write to excel the right count of rows, but the data inside the file contains only the last data of the list, why?
(in my case 84 rows with repeate data that inside `arr[list.Capacity -1]`)
Thanks!!

```
  List<string> titles = new List<string>() {   "מספר רשיון", "אזור" ,"ישוב", "תאריך אחרון להגשת השגה","מין העץ", "ערך מין העץ", "סה'כ להעתקה" , "סה'כ לכריתה"
            ,"סה'כ לשימור", "מבקש" , "רחוב" , "מספר", "גוש" , "חלקה"};

            List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>(pagedList.Capacity);
            foreach (var result in pagedList)
            {
                
                list.Add(new[] {result.LicenseId?.ToString(),result.ZoneName, result.CityName?.ToString(),
                result.AppealLastDate?.ToString(),  result.TreeName?.ToString(),  result.TreeType.HasValue ? result.TreeType.Value.ToString() :"", result.Copying?.ToString(),
                    result.Unproot?.ToString(), result.Conservation?.ToString(), result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.CustomerName).FirstOrDefault(), result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Street).FirstOrDefault(),
                    result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.HomeNumber).FirstOrDefault(),result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Block).FirstOrDefault(),result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Parcel).FirstOrDefault(),

                }); ;
            }
            
            using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var workSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                foreach (var arr in list)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= list.Capacity; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= titles.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value = arr[j-1];
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
```

Comment: The 2 inner `for` loops are always writing to the exact same cells for each `arr` in the `list`. This is the line that is always overwriting the prior values: `workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value = arr[j-1];`

Comment: @MetroSmurf ok so how should I code it right for every row,column?

Comment: Is the `foreach()` line necessary @bob2habanay? You seem to be iterating over the rows in the first `for()` loop. Try commenting it out and testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comments, the 2 inner `for` loops are always writing to the exact same cells, effectively overwriting the prior values which is why only the last row of data is being added to the worksheet.

Only one list is needed to hold all the rows, including the titles. The following commented code should be close enough to help resolve the issue:

```cs
// only one list is needed to hold all the rows
var rows = new List<string[]>();

// add the headers first
rows.Add( new[] { "מספר רשיון", "אזור" ,"ישוב", "תאריך אחרון להגשת השגה",
                  "מין העץ", "ערך מין העץ", "סה'כ להעתקה" , "סה'כ לכריתה",
                  "סה'כ לשימור", "מבקש" , "רחוב" , "מספר", "גוש" , "חלקה" } );

// then add the values to the list
foreach (var result in pagedList)
{
    rows.Add( new[] { result.LicenseId?.ToString(),result.ZoneName, result.CityName?.ToString(),
                      result.AppealLastDate?.ToString(),  result.TreeName?.ToString(), 
                      result.TreeType.HasValue ? result.TreeType.Value.ToString() : "",
                      result.Copying?.ToString(), result.Unproot?.ToString(), result.Conservation?.ToString(),
                      result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.CustomerName).FirstOrDefault(),
                      result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Street).FirstOrDefault(),
                      result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.HomeNumber).FirstOrDefault(),
                      result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Block).FirstOrDefault(),
                      result.ExpandRows.Select(p => p.Parcel).FirstOrDefault() } );
}

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var workSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    // go through each of the rows
    foreach (int r = 0; r < rows.Count; r++)
    {
        string[] row = rows[r];

        // now add the contents of each row to the worksheet
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[r, i].Value = row[i];
        }
    }
}
```